# How to join lines in a \pgfextra block

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core

I want to make a block using a style "overlay" (`append after command`) that looks like this but with joined line segments.

[image]

Is there any way to modify my code to achieve joins? Unfortunately I don't really know how to use `\pgfextra`, I modified another .tex file I had lying around which is based off of a TikZ example that I have misplaced, so this is cargo cult TikZ programming for me.

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
    block/.style={
        thick,draw=black,
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        minimum height=10mm, node distance=5mm,
        top color=white,
        drop shadow
    },
      satstyle/.style={
        append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\lastnode\tikzlastnode} 
            ($(\lastnode.south) + (0,0.3em)$) edge
            ($(\lastnode.north) + (0,-0.3em)$) 
            ($(\lastnode.west) + (0.3em,0)$) edge
            ($(\lastnode.east) + (-0.3em,0)$) 
            ($(\lastnode.south west) + (0.5em,0.5em)$) edge[-, very thick]
            ($(\lastnode.south) + (-0.2em,0.5em)$)
            ($(\lastnode.south) + (-0.2em,0.5em)$) edge[-, very thick]
            ($(\lastnode.north) + (0.2em,-0.5em)$) 
            ($(\lastnode.north) + (0.2em,-0.5em)$) edge[-, very thick]
            ($(\lastnode.north east) + (-0.5em,-0.5em)$)
        }
       },
    >=latex
    ]
\node (X) [block, satstyle] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \pgfextra is used to insert LaTeX commands into the middle of a \path.  It simply turns the TikZ parser off.

Comment: Hmm..., ok I found some docs for PGF path commands, what am i allowed to do here? https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse21.html

Comment: The problem isn't the \pgfextra.  All that does is assign \lastnode to \tikzlastnode.  The problem is that edge can only connect two points at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,calc}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
block/.style = {
    rectangle, draw, thick, fill=white,
              minimum height=9mm, minimum width=12mm,
              drop shadow
                  },
  sat/.style = {block,  
    path picture={
        \draw[-latex,thin]
    ($(\ppbb.south) + (0,0.5ex)$) edge ($(\ppbb.north) + (0,-0.5ex)$)
    ($(\ppbb.west)  + (0.5ex,0)$)  to  ($(\ppbb.east)  + (-0.5ex,0)$);
        \draw[very thick] 
    ($(\ppbb.south west) + (1ex,1ex)$) --
        ($(\ppbb.south) + (-1ex,1ex)$) --
        ($(\ppbb.north) + (1ex,-1ex)$) --
        ($(\ppbb.north east) + (-1ex,-1ex)$);
                        }% end path picture
                    },
                    ]
\node (X) [sat] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I slightly redesign your saturation symbol:

[image]

Edges as you draw, draw only segments between given coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

adapting Zarko's answer to my original design, I needed to use `\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}` and

```
satstyle/.style = {
    path picture={
    \draw[-, thin]
        ($(\ppbb.south) + (0,0.3em)$) edge ($(\ppbb.north) + (0,-0.3em)$)
        ($(\ppbb.west)  + (0.3em,0)$)  to  ($(\ppbb.east)  + (-0.3em,0)$);
    \draw[very thick] 
        ($(\ppbb.south west) + (0.5em,0.5em)$) --
        ($(\ppbb.south) + (-0.2em,0.5em)$) --
        ($(\ppbb.north) + (0.2em,-0.5em)$) --
        ($(\ppbb.north east) + (-0.5em,-0.5em)$);
      }% end path picture
   },
```

[image]

full example:

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,calc}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
    block/.style={
        thick,draw=black,
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        minimum height=10mm, node distance=5mm,
        top color=white,
        drop shadow
    },
    satstyle/.style = {
        path picture={
        \draw[-, thin]
            ($(\ppbb.south) + (0,0.3em)$) edge ($(\ppbb.north) + (0,-0.3em)$)
            ($(\ppbb.west)  + (0.3em,0)$)  to  ($(\ppbb.east)  + (-0.3em,0)$);
        \draw[very thick] 
            ($(\ppbb.south west) + (0.5em,0.5em)$) --
            ($(\ppbb.south) + (-0.2em,0.5em)$) --
            ($(\ppbb.north) + (0.2em,-0.5em)$) --
            ($(\ppbb.north east) + (-0.5em,-0.5em)$);
          }% end path picture
       },
    >=latex
    ]
\node (X) [block, satstyle] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there special reason that you repeat `node distance` in `box` style definition? Also, if you define `minimum width` and `minimum height`, the `minimum size` is surplus. Similarly `-` in `\draw[-,thin] is not necessary ...

Comment: not sure. thanks. I usually just take the last tikz file I work on and modify it to what I need.